# Object reference not set to an instance of an object. How to view the stack

Tags: c#, asp.net, debugging, devexpress, stack-trace

I have "trace" on but do not get a "stack trace" for this error in my Asp.Net development project. On other errors I have seen stack traces, but my question is why don't I see one now?

This is about a DevExpress gridview. Could it be that DevExpress errors are handled differently from plain Asp.Net code?

I have set breakpoints on all sorts of interesting places but no avail. Perhaps there are errors that are not associated with stack traces?

I tried with Firefox and IE browsers.

Kind of stuck, hope this to be a silly problem.

Comment: Is it an exception or a script error? Exceptions can have inner exceptions.. perhaps the stack trace is there..

Comment: It is a popup in the browser titled "Message from webpage", an exclamation icon, OK button and text "Object ref...".

Comment: Can you show us the code in question?

Comment: I find it hard to select code to show because I have no clue where the error might be located. aspx, aspx.cs, appcode/*cs. I use code found on http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E4099 , most works even the custom filter code, but after filtering it pops up with "Object ref not set..." I also feel it might not be a DevExpress problem. A stack trace would really help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**From**: [ASPxGridView - Object reference not set to an instance of an object](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q358147)

This issue is caused by the fact that some object reference equals "null". I suggest that you determine the problematic reference in the following manner:

- Disable ASPxGridView's callbacks by setting the `ASPxGridView.EnableCallBacks` property to "`false`";
- Perform the required steps to reproduce the issue.

You will receive the Server Error screen with information about the exception that has been thrown (and the problematic reference/code line).
If this does not help, please provide us with a sample working project (containing only the problematic ASPxGridView bound to any portable datasource) that illustrates the issue, so that we can examine it on our side under the same conditions.

> Also, the exception you see is raised in server code and to be able to
>   catch it, please adjust the VS as shown below:
>
> 1. Go to the Debug-->Exceptions dialog and check the Common Language Runtime Exceptions and check the check box in the Thrown column;
> 2. Go to the Tools-->Options-->Debugging and uncheck the Enable Just My Code (Managed Only) check box.

After doing these all stuff, you are not able to get the error then provide your markup  to check what is actual problem..

Comment: Disabling ASPxGridView's callbacks helped. Now I am getting the stack trace. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

In case you're using Visual Studio, have you checked `Debug -> Exceptions -> Common Language Runtime Exceptions` checkbox ?

Comment: Good point! It was checked "User Unhandled". Changed to Thrown. No improvement. I will also try the other classes of exceptions in this option dialog.

Comment: It turned out that these settings did not really matter. I had to disable the callbacks of the gridview control, see the other solution above. Thanks for your suggestions anyway!

Comment: sorry it didn't help :)

Answer (score 0):

you may use try catch block in your code to get the location where the code is breaking else set the Common Language runtime thrown to true in exception window(to open this window press ALT +CTRL+E)

Comment: I stepped through all of my code; no exception occurred there.